# Figma can't find password dots shortcut

Tags: operating-system, keyboard-shortcuts, figma

there is a problem in Figma shortcuts I can't get password dots by alt+7 or alt+0139
please answer

Answer (score 0):

It works, but you have to use **`ALT+0149`**, not `ALT+0139`.

**Screenshot:**

[image]